# Show items by user_role

Tags: php

I have this code, start with

```
    {foreach $items as $item}
```

I know that I must connect below code to start code

```
    $user = new WP_User( $item->post_author );

    if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
    echo $role;
```

I need hide items only for one role "directory_4". If post_author item have a role "directory_4" items will be hide and if post_author item have a other role will be showed all items.

Very thank you for your help.

Comment: This looks like pure PHP. Check `$role` and see if it matches "directory_4".

Comment: please can you send me example code, add in foreach item, very thank you

Comment: Tomas, your first block of code is broken-- `{foreach $items as $item}`-- to the point that it looks more like Python than PHP. Secondly, the code your are missing is a very simple PHP `if` conditional. ___Look it up___. PHP's docs are very good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to check if a user has a role.  Note that I used your way of getting the WP_User, but there are others:

```
$user = new WP_User( $item->post_author );
// $user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id()); // another way to get logged in user
if ( !user_can($user->ID,'directory_4') ) {
    // show items, user does not have directory_4 role
}
```

Comment: Very thank you for your answer, but I need import this to this code http://itweb.sk/script.txt that It will display items only from other user roles, Very thank you for your time